# Destoy component in middle of method

Tags: angular

I have method in my component

```
closeWidget() {
    this.closeEvent.emit();
    this.analytics.widgetClosed();
}
```

will widgetClosed be called after closeEvent emitted and component closed?

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've told us, all we can say is that the two steps will be called in sequence before the `closeWidget` method completes.